# Google Spreadsheet Script - the value whcih added up two integer is wrong

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use Range.getValues() to get an Array.
Now I want to add up two values of the Array, so first I force Integer instead to String.
I refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121837/google-spreadsheet-script-getvalues-force-int-instead-of-string), and my codes are:

```
var array = Range.getValues(); //suppose the array includes two values.
                               //array[0] is 5, array[1] is 7.56.
var count = Number(array[0]) + Number(array[1]);
Logger.log(count);
```

I found the answer is 12.55999999, and I try to log each value.

```
Logger.log(Number(array[0]));
Logger.log(Number(array[1]));
```

The result is 5 and 7.56.

I use parseFloat() to add up it, and returned the same result (12.55999999).

Someone can help me to slove this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) can be helpful.

```
console.log((parseFloat("5") + parseFloat("7.56")).toFixed(2)); // 12.56
```