# Google Scripts Concatenating rather than adding

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When I run my script rather than adding what I think should be two numbers, it concatenates...

I feel like I'm watching that Abbot and Costello bit. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o1SAS8KyMs

```
  var weekNum = e.parameter.weekListBox;
  weekNum = weekNum + 3;
```

weekListBox has the values from 1 to 15.
I am trying to offset it by 3.

However 1 + 3 yields 13, not 4 as I was expecting. Drove me nuts till I realized why this was happening.

So how do I get it to add?

Thanks

Comment: weekNum += 3 also concatenates...

Comment: Google-apps-script is JavaScript .. suggest you use parseInt. see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: [M Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025019/m-jesse): Very good the Abbott & Costello sketch. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out, this is the only solution that worked for me... Very strange problem.

[Google Spreadsheet Script getValues - Force int instead of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121837/google-spreadsheet-script-getvalues-force-int-instead-of-string)

Answered by hoogamaphone

> You can do this easily using the unary '+' operator as follows:
>
> First get your values from your spreadsheet using getValue() or
>   getValues(). Suppose you get two such values, and store them in A = 1
>   and B = 2. You can force them to be recognized as numbers by using any
>   math binary operator except for +, which concatenates strings, so A -
>   B = -1, while A + B will return '12'.
>
> You can force the variables to be numbers simply by using the + unary
>   operator with any variable that might be interpreted as a string. For
>   example, +A + +B will return the correct value of 3.

Comment: Are you saying the other code(s) did not return the expected result? I doubt it.... seriously.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above explains the issue but does not provide a solution (except in comments but `parseInt()` is not the only/best solution).

The reason you have that issue is that the value returned by `e.parameter.weekListBox;` is actually **a string** (it is actually always the case except for dates which are date objects) so the result you get is the normal string concatenation (string+number=new string).

One simple solution is to change your code as follows :

```
  var weekNum = Number(e.parameter.weekListBox);// make it a number
  weekNum = weekNum + 3;// and the result will be a sum
```

Answer (score -1):

See

```
function myFunction() {
    var aa = 1;
    var ab = aa + 3;

    var ba = "1";
    var bb = ba + 3;
}
```

ab = 4
but
bb = "13"